# Prove that $F(a_1, ... , a_i)$ contains no $p$th roots of unity not in $F(a_1, ... , a_{i-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, prime-numbers, extension-field, roots-of-unity

For context: each $a_i$ is a $p$th [$p=$prime] root of some element in the field $F(a_1,..., a_{i-1})$.

The author claims that:

"if $a_i$ is a $p$th root we can assume that $F(a_1, ... , a_i)$ contains no $p$th roots of unity not in $F(a_1, ... , a_{i-1})$ unless $a_i$ itself is a $p$th root of unity. "

---

How could one prove this statement?

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts!

---

Edit: for further clarification on the meaning of $F(a_1, ..., a_i)$. The author seems to start with a generic field $F$, and adjoin a $p$th root of some element in $F$, that is, we adjoin $a_1=f_1^{1/p_1}$, $f_1∈F$ and so we get $F(a_1)$. Now we adjoin $a_2=f_2^{1/p_2}$, $f_2∈F(a_1)$ getting $F(a_1, a_2)$ and the process is repeated $i$ times, getting $F(a_1, ... , a_i)$.

Comment: I would appreciate some clarification. What do you mean exactly by each $a_i$ being a $p$th root of some element in the field? Does this mean that every element in $F(a_1, ..., a_{i-1})  $ is a $p$th root of another element in the field? Also, how can you know that  $F(a_1,...a_i)$ is also a field?, since $a_i$ is not in the original field.

Comment: You probably meant "contains no new root of unity unless $a_i$ is itself a root of unity" (example in finite fields all elements are roots of unity) @marlasca23 It means $F_i = F_{i-1}(\sqrt[p_i]{c_i})$ for some $c_i \in F_{i-1}$, ie. a [radical extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_extension). Example $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/13},\sqrt{-1})$

Comment: @reuns. I copied it as the author wrote it. What do you mean with $K(ζ_p)/K$ is never of degree $p$? By 'degree' we are refering to the dimension of the vector field of $K(ζ_p)$ over $K$, right? Although what exactly is this $K(ζ_p)/K$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $p$ is prime, $K$ is an extension of your $F$ of characteristic not $p$ and $\ a \in K$ is not a root of unity and $a^{1/p} \not \in K$. Then $[K(a^{1/p}):K]=p$ (see below)

If $\zeta_n \in K(a^{1/p}),\zeta_n \not \in K$ then $K(\zeta_{n})/K$ is a non-trivial subextension, thus of degree dividing $p$, thus of degree $p$, thus $K(a^{1/p}) = K(\zeta_n)$.  Take the smallest such $n$.

Find the largest $m | n$ such that $\zeta_m \in K$.

- In characteristic $0$ ,  $\ [K(\zeta_{n}):K(\zeta_m)] = \frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(m)}$ which means $p | m $ and $n = pm$, so wlog you can set $a= \zeta_m$.
- In characteristic $q$, $\ [K(\zeta_{n}):K(\zeta_m)] \ \ \ | \ \ \frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(m)}$ thus again it means $p | m $ and $n = pm$, so wlog you can set $a= \zeta_m$.

---

$X^p-a = \prod_{l=1}^p (X-\zeta_p^l  a^{1/p})$ so that  $K(\zeta_p,a^{1/p})/K(\zeta_p)$ is a Galois extension. Any element $\sigma \in Gal(K(\zeta_p,a^{1/p})/K(\zeta_p))$ is of the form $ a^{1/p} \mapsto \zeta_p^l  a^{1/p}$ which has order $p$, thus $K(\zeta_p,a^{1/p})/K(\zeta_p)$ is of degree $p$ and so is $K(a^{1/p})/K$.